# Using text file with DataProvider in TestNG

Tags: java, testing, testng, dataprovider

I'm trying to make some tests for a java program using TestNG with a dataProvider.

When I populate the dataProvider manually, everything works perfect. Now I'm trying to use a text file with the data provider where each line is the input for the test. I need more than just print each line, I have to read each line, manipulate and generate an **expected result**. So, for each line I will send to the test, the line itself and the expected result. Then in the test the line will be tested by the program and generate the **actual result**, to finally compare the **expected** and **actual** results.

I have made a first attempt, but it's not working as I expect and the performance is really poor.

I have search on the web, but I still can't find the correct way to bind data to a dataProvider from a text file (.txt)

my current code (simplified) is:

```
@DataProvider(name="fileData")
  public Object[][] testData() throws IOException {
      int numLines = 0;
      int currentLine = 0;
      String sended = "";
      File file = new File("file.txt");

      //counting lines from file
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      while ((br.readLine()) != null){
          numLines++;
      }
      br.close();

      //extracting lines to send to test
      String[][] testData = new String[numLines][2];
      BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      while ((sended = br2.readLine()) != null){
          String expected = sended.substring(50, 106) + "00" + sended.substring(106, 154); 
           testData[currentLine][0] = sended;
           testData[currentLine][1] = expected;
           currentLine++;
      }
      br2.close();
      return testData;
  }
```

Hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: What is your current code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some sample code, provided you use Java 7:

```
@DataProvider
public Iterator<Object[]> testData()
    throws IOException
{
    final List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final String line: Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("whatever"),
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        list.add(new Object[]{ line, process(line) };

    return list.iterator();
}

private static Whatever process(final String line)
{
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: I will try this way, I think it should be what I was looking for. Just one thing, the "wathever" in: Paths.get("whatever") should be replaced with the path to my text file, right?

Comment: Yes. But this is an example... I guess your file is in the classpath, so in this case the code will be different.

Comment: I see that you have pasted your code now... The problem here is that you seem to replicate the logic of your method in the test. Not very viable imho...

Comment: I already tried the sample code, it didn't solve the performance issue. But it solved another issue, with my code I had to read the file twice and using this way I have to read just once. Thanks for your help

Comment: This snippet, while useful in context, has many errors and will not compile. I would have made the edits but the 'edit queue is full'.

Comment: @oche this is a snippet; of course it will not compile per se; don't tell me you expected it to...

Comment: @fge I would expect an answer on SO to be valid (Java) code